# How to package Chrome extension (generate .CRX file) in the command line

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How do I generate a .CRX file in the command line? I tried `chrome --pack-extension=PATH_TO_MY_UNPACKED_EXTENSION`, but it doesn't do anything. No output file, no messages, nothing. My extension has a `manifest.json` and a `rules.json`. If I do it manually through the Chrome app (go to `chrome://extensions/` -> click the "Pack extension" file), it works just fine. The `chrome` binary is definitely in my PATH, since if I only enter `chrome` into the command line, the Chrome app opens. I'm on Windows 10 if that's relevant.

Comment: https://crbug.com/1498558

Comment: Reverted back to v118, doesn't work either. Guess I'll just have to do it manually.

Comment: v117 works for me. You can use a portable/standalone build I guess.

Comment: Not sure it matters. I tried reinstalling Chrome and now I can't even do it manually because the extension is "invalid" (error: `CRX_REQUIRED_PROOF`). After some searching it seems like I can't fix it.